# How can I make two files together in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pygame

I am making a game by using pygame and I made each section in a separate file such as a home page, an instruction page, actual game and so on, and I have no idea on how to put them all together. I had considered using
this code

```
from graphics import*

w = GraphWin("Window", 600,400)

playing = True
while playing:
    click = w.getMouse()
    potato = click.getX()
    carrot = click.getY()

    if potato < 300 and carrot < 200:
        newWin = GraphWin("New", 200, 200)
    if potato > 300 and carrot > 200:
        w.setBackground("blue")
    if potato < 300 and carrot > 200:
        playing = False

    w.close()
    n = GraphWin("Homepage", 500, 200)
    n.getMouse()
    n.close()
```

But I still have no idea how to put them all together. Can you please help me on how to make these two files go together? This file is the home page:

```
from graphics import* 
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

padWidth = 500 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 600 # the length of the game
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

def writeIns(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 29) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, red) #red text
    textpos = (158,417)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    
def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Shooting game') #the title of the game
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    
    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                
        drawObject(background, 0, 0) #display the background 

        
        pygame.draw.rect(gamePad, black, (120,400,250,70))

        writeIns('INSTRUCTIONS')
        
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()
       

initGame()
runGame()
```

and this one is the instruction page

```
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep


padWidth = 500 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 600 # the length of the game
red = (255,0,0)

def writeExit(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 20) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, red) #black text
    textpos = (625, 60)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    
def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, instructions
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('shooting game') #the title of the game
    instructions = pygame.image.load('instructions.png') #import the background image
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, instructions
    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        drawObject(instructions, 0, 0)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)
        
    pygame.quit()

initGame()
runGame()
```

So, I wish that, when a button is pressed from the homepage, it will move to the instruction page.

Comment: You can import one file to another file by using the code `from FileName import *` (Replace `FileName` with the name of the python file). This will give you all access the functions in the python file.

Comment: You are better off putting all the code in one python file though.

Comment: Ohh but it is not working thank you tho

Comment: @talktalk Import them into one file and then do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319083/6486738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the files, you need to make two key changes:

- Import the other source files into the main file
- Convert the imported source to classes to prevent overlap in variables and functions

Here is the working code. The starting file is gamex.py, the imported files are ghome.py and ginstructions.py.

gamex.py

```
from graphics import *

# import home and instructions
from ghome import home
from ginstructions import instructions


# call home screen
h = home()  # create instance of home
h.initGame()
h.runGame()

# call instructions screen
i = instructions()  # create instance of instructions
i.initGame()
i.runGame()


w = GraphWin("Window", 600,400)

playing = True
while playing:
    click = w.getMouse()
    potato = click.getX()
    carrot = click.getY()

    if potato < 300 and carrot < 200:
        newWin = GraphWin("New", 200, 200)
    if potato > 300 and carrot > 200:
        w.setBackground("blue")
    if potato < 300 and carrot > 200:
        playing = False

    w.close()
    n = GraphWin("Homepage", 500, 200)
    n.getMouse()
    n.close()
```

ghome.py

```
from graphics import* 
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

class home():
    def __init__(self):
        self.padWidth = 500 #the width the of game 
        self.padHeight = 600 # the length of the game
        self.white = (255,255,255)
        self.black = (0,0,0)
        self.red = (255,0,0)

    def writeIns(self, text):
        global gamePad
        textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 29) #textfont of the game message 
        text = textfont.render(text, True, self.red) #red text
        textpos = (158,417)
        gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
        pygame.display.update()
        
    def drawObject(obj, x, y):
        global gamePad
        gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

    def initGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background
        pygame.init()
        gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((self.padWidth, self.padHeight))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Shooting game') #the title of the game
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def runGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background
        
        onGame = False
        while not onGame:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: break

#            self.drawObject(background, 0, 0) #display the background 
            pygame.draw.rect(gamePad, self.black, (120,400,250,70))
            self.writeIns('INSTRUCTIONS')
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()
```

ginstructions.py

```
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

class instructions():
    def __init__(self):
        self.padWidth = 500 #the width the of game 
        self.padHeight = 600 # the length of the game
        self.red = (255,0,0)

    def writeExit(self,text):
        global gamePad
        textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 20) #textfont of the game message 
        text = textfont.render(text, True, self.red) #black text
        textpos = (625, 60)
        gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
        pygame.display.update()
        
    def drawObject(self,obj, x, y):
        global gamePad
        gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

    def initGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, instructions
        pygame.init()
        gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((self.padWidth, self.padHeight))
        pygame.display.set_caption('shooting game') #the title of the game
        instructions = pygame.image.load('instructions.png') #import the background image
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def runGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, instructions
        onGame = False
        while not onGame:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: break
            self.drawObject(instructions, 0, 0)
            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(60)
            
        pygame.quit()
```